# Why does a subscript grab the argument of `\text` but not of `\operatorname`?

Tags: macros, amsmath

A friend shared with me a LaTeX document using essentially the following code, which I was sure wouldn't compile:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\(a_\text b\)
\end{document}
```

It compiles just fine, with the same result as if more braces were introduced (i.e., `\(a_{\text{b}}\)`).  I was curious what makes this work, and tried:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\(a_\operatorname b\)
\end{document}
```

This yields the error

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.3     \(a_\operatorname
                         b\)
```

Inserting braces as `\(a_\operatorname{b}\)` gives essentially the same error (although, of course, `\(a_{\operatorname{b}}\)` works).  Why do these macros behave differently?

Comment: Presumably because the output ends up being braced/grouped such that what ever ends up being he argument for `_` is actually a single group. Thus if the replacement of `\text b` is similar to (it is not) `{\textnormal b}` then it works, but if the replacement is `\textnormal b` (no braces) then it does not work. This is why we always recommend using braces on sub- and superscript (unless it is a single number or symbol and there is no confusing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, `\(a_\text b\)` is wrong input (it works, yes, but it's wrong nonetheless). The correct input would be `\(a_{\text{b}}\)`, and the same for the `\operatorname` case. One case works and the other does not due to implementation details of these two macros, which should not be relied upon (they are not likely to change in the near future, but either way. . .)

That said, `\text` works that way because (after three expansion steps) the first token TeX sees is a `{`, so it essentially inserts the `{`. . .`}` you left out. The first expansion of `\text` is `\protect\text␣␣`. Here `\protect` is `\relax` (which is ignored here) and `\text␣␣` expands to `\text@` (after checking that we're in math mode), and `\text@` starts with a `{`.

`\operatorname`, on the other hand, contains an `\@ifstar` test, which is not expandable, so the first token TeX sees (after four expansion steps) is `\let`, which is invalid there, thus it raises an error. You can reproduce the same error by writing `\(a_\let\)`.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted for the very helpful answer, but with a little reluctance because I think the 'wrong' isn't terribly helpful here.  (I'm not sure what it means other than "not best practices", which I think has less of a moralistic connotation, or "subject to implementation details of the macro", which seems to be true for any macro.)

Comment: @LSpice Yes, you are correct (many things in (La)TeX work (or do not) as they do due to implementation details). With "wrong" I meant that in the LaTeX (and `amsmath`, since that's an `amsmath` macro) manuals, you are taught to always use braces for subscripts and for arguments, since otherwise you may fall for implementation detail traps :-)

Comment: Thanks; [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523172/why-does-a-subscript-grab-the-argument-of-text-but-not-of-operatorname/523176#comment1323329_523176) definition of 'wrong' makes a lot more sense to me than the moralistic way in which I originally read it.

Comment: Is it just a matter of being expandable (rather than necessarily a catcode-1 character)?  I notice that `\def\identity#1{#1}\(a_\identity b\)` (or even, of course, just `\(a_b\)`) doesn't produce an error, even though there's no explicit brace involved.  (I always get confused about the definition of expandability, so I don't know if catcode 11 counts as 'expandable', or if that only applies to macros.)

Comment: @LSpice Two things are involved here. First is the fact that TeX understands both `a_b` and `a_{b}` the same, so you can input either. The second is expandability: your `\identity` example works because TeX expands it and eventually sees `a_b`, which is fine. However `a_\identity{bc}` will not work as `a_\text{bc}` because it will expand to `a_bc`, which TeX sees the same as `a_{b}c`. The braces (rather, catcode-1 tokens) are necessary when grouping multiple tokens in the subscript. And no, character tokens are not expandable (either catcode 11 or 12).

Comment: @LSpice the thing I think you are missing is that the tex primitive `_` and a macro pick up their arguments in completely different ways. An undelimited macro argument `#1` is always a single token or an explicit brace group. But a tex primitive `_` expands tokens as needed to find the first non-expandable token and then takes an implicit or explicit `{` token to start a grouped subscript, or the single non brace non expandable token otherwise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, [thanks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523172/why-does-a-subscript-grab-the-argument-of-text-but-not-of-operatorname/523176#comment1323347_523176); you are right about at least part of what I was missing.  Does "implicit `{`" mean, as in PhelypeOleinik's explanation, one that comes indirectly by expansion, or is it one that isn't in the source at all, even after expansion, and that TeX inserts?  If the latter, then under what circumstances does that happen?

Comment: I may post an answer comments don't really work

Comment: @LSpice Implicit as `\bgroup` in `\(a_\bgroup\operatorname b}\)`

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Assuming standard catcode regimes so that `{` starts a group and `}` end it, then then...

Official LaTex documentation will tell you to always brace the arguments. Partly it does this to avoid having to document what happens if you omit the braces....

A macro scans for an undelimited argument without expanding any tokens, if the next non-space token is a `{` then the (content of the) group is taken, otherwise the single token is taken as the argument.

Conversely most TeX primitives such as `_` or `\hbox` recursively expand the following token until arriving at a non expandable token and then accepting an implicit or explicit `{` token to start a grouped argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand \zzA{1234}

\newcommand \zzB{{1234}}

\newcommand \zzC{\zzca}
\newcommand\zzca{\bgroup 1234}



\begin{document}

1 \fbox\zzA  \fbox{\zzA}

2 $X_\zzA   \quad X_{\zzA}$

3 \fbox\zzB  \fbox{\zzB}

4 $X_\zzB  \quad X_{\zzB}$

5 a \fbox\zzC\egroup  b\fbox{\zzC \egroup}

6 $X_\zzC}  \quad X_{\zzC}}$



\end{document}
```

so note in line 1 the macro `\fbox` takes all of 1234 as an argument in `\fbox\zzA` but `X_\zzA` expands `\zzA` and so only takes 1 as the subscript.

The behaviour of line 5 is particularly "interesting" we could document a trace through the code and say why no box appears in the unbraced version, but documenting that `\fbox` (and all latex commands) should always be used with braced arguments is less likely to scare off 99% of the user base.

Comment: For passersby, this was a response to my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523172/why-does-a-subscript-grab-the-argument-of-text-but-not-of-operatorname/523184#comment1323351_523176) in another comment thread.  Thanks very much for this thorough workout of the rules and edge cases!  As a mathematician, thinking about TeX as I would about math—rather than just as a tool for typesetting math—makes this sort of thing deeply fascinating to me.